# Can you help me fix code to show the occurrence of items in a list, for only the first five items?

Tags: python

I created this file as part of homework for a class and already got 100%. However, the instructor had originally wanted to also show frequencies for only the first 5 items in each column. Here is the code.

```
#PE 8
#11-2-17



def main():
    #import data
    winninglist=get_data()


    #find frequency for lotterynumber 1-69
    frequency=find_frequency(winninglist)


    #sort the frequency
    sortedlist=sorting(frequency)

    print("The 10 most common numbers and their corresponding frequencies are: ")
    print(sortedlist[:10])

    print("The 10 least common numbers and their corresponding frequencies are: ")
    print(sortedlist[-10:])


    #find the 10 most overdue numbers

    #find the frequency of 1-69 for the regular numbers, and 1-26 for powerball



def get_data():

    #read from the file
    infile=open('power.txt','r')
    lines=infile.readlines()
    infile.close()


    #initialize winninglist
    winninglist=[]


    #processraw data line by line, taking away new character lines, split using space, add to winninglist
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        lines[i]=lines[i].rstrip('\n')
        item=lines[i].split()
        winninglist+=item



    return winninglist

def find_frequency(winninglist):
    #frequency should be a list
    frequency=[0]*69

    #count the occurance of each number

    for i in range(69):
        for item in winninglist:
            if int(item)==(i+1):
               frequency[i]+=1

    #print(frequency)
    return frequency

def sorting(frequency):

    #record both the number and frequency
    pb_frequency=[]

    for i in range(len(frequency)):
        pb_frequency.append([i+1, frequency[i]])

    #print(pb_frequency)
    #now sort using bubble sorting
    for i in range(len(pb_frequency)):
        max=i
        for j in range(i+1, (len(pb_frequency))):
            if pb_frequency[j][1]>pb_frequency[max][1]:
                max=j

        #max has the index of the highest frequency number for this round
        #we make the exchange to bubble the largest one
        temp1=pb_frequency[i][0]
        temp2=pb_frequency[i][1]
        pb_frequency[i][0]=pb_frequency[max][0]
        pb_frequency[i][1]=pb_frequency[max][1]
        pb_frequency[max][0]=temp1
        pb_frequency[max][1]=temp2
    #print(pb_frequency)
    return pb_frequency

main()
```

Here is the format of the txt file:

17 22 36 37 52 24

14 22 52 54 59 04

05 08 29 37 38 24

10 14 30 40 51 01

This is how the original file looks, and I thought it would be easy to do the rest. But, I have been struggling. I tried doing a split [0:5] and appending the results to determine the frequency after that, but could never make it work (kept getting one error after another). Could anyone help steer me in the right direction?

Comment: However, the instructor had originally wanted show frequencies for only the first 5 items in each line.but you were doing for 10?

Comment: Edited to show proper txt formatting. To clarify: what I am trying to achieve is the same result output style, just using only the first five columns' numbers.

Comment: still can't understand? an example. 1 3 2 4 5 6=> 1 2 3 4 5 (5 low number of 6 in the line. " then only the last item in each line" means 6 as that is last item of first line?

Comment: Sorry, I am having trouble explaining. If you'd like, here are the files so you could see the full picture and output (hope this is allowed) https://ufile.io/zy4iv. But, to try to restate: the result shows the top ten frequently recurring numbers in the list, with their corresponding frequencies. I want the same result, just without using the last column of numbers. So, without using the 24, 04, 24, and 01 in this particular sample of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I get your question now and think that your code needs only a minor change:

When you are appending list to your returning list (winninglist), slice the last index of the appending list.

Do the following:

change

```
winninglist+=item
```

to

```
winninglist+=item[0:len(item)-1]
```

Comment: Wow, that was easier than I thought it would be. Could you help with another adjustment? I need help showing the 10 most overdue numbers. Each line has an implied date attached to it, the first line being the oldest, so, I would need code to show the 10 numbers that have occurred least recently. (This would be out of all columns, so, disregarding last solution.)

Comment: yeah :-) It will take a little time though

Comment: I posted this as an additional question, I don't know if this would help you with the karma system on this site. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47720965/how-to-show-the-ten-most-overdue-numbers-in-a-list